# quill editor removing styles?

Tags: angular, ngx-quill

I am using quill in angular 8 and when i update quill data, it deletes styles and update only html tags

this is my code before updating data from quill editor

```
 <style type="text/css">
   @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
   #s2_rewardCliamForm {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
   background-color: transparent;
   }
</style>
<p class="ql-align-center">
   <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
   <img src="//cdn.image.com/custom_images/8989170/BSZFB1_x_copy.png">
   </a>
</p>
```

after updation its updating below html data

```
<p class="ql-align-center">
   <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
   <img src="//cdn.image.com/custom_images/8989170/BSZFB1_x_copy.png">
   </a>
</p>
```

its removing style tag